# Implementing View Pager in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I have to implement horizontal swipe view as a paging system and each page shows data from the server, means each page shows dynamic data at run time. I think it is possible with View Pager but in View Pager there is no any fixed layout which is shown on particular page, So, firstly how can we do that, secondly in View Pager all views should be predesigned or preimplemented or we can say that Number of Views we must know. But when we want to take it dynamic when user swipe a page then it goes to next page but progressbar will appear to show the data for corresponding page. So, how can we do this also? Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**View Pager:**

**View Pager Demo**`http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

to detect page changement and so loading the page content

Comment: Where we load the content, we can't add xml's in Views dynamically.

Comment: You can have fixe empty layout for each page and inflate sub-layout xml dynamically.

Comment: I don't want to create many layouts because all layouts are same, but values are different in each layout.

Comment: So I don't understand, why do you want to add xml's in Views dynamically?
May you show more Code to better understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution isn't in ViewPager but in your custom PagerAdapter. You must subclass the PagerAdapter and add a method to add content to your adapter and call in this method the method notifyDataSetChanged :

```
public void addPage(Object page) {
    // Add page to the arraylist of adapter 
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```